# Swift 5.1: How do I call map on a collection of one type and return another of a different type?

Tags: swift

I've been playing about with functional programming in Swift. However, I've encountered a problem.

If I call map on a collection of one type, how do I create a new collection of another type?

```swift
var fontFamilyMembers = [[Any]]()

//...
let postscriptNames = fontFamilyMembers.map {
    [
        "name": $0[0] as! String,
        "weight": $0[2] as! Int,
        "traits": $0[3] as! UInt
    ]
}

// Error: Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'count'
lengths = postscriptNames.map { $0["name"].count }
```

I understand I need to cast `$0["name"]` as a string. Why do I have to do that when I have already done it above? (`"name": $0[0] as! String`). Is that because `postscriptNames` is also type `[[Any]]()`?

I've tried this:

```
// Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to closure result type 'String'
fontPostscriptNames = postscriptNames.map { ($0["name"] as! String).count }.joined(separator: "\n")
```

…but know I'm doubly confused.

How do I get map to return the count of each `"name"`?

### Update

My original question still stands. However, I can avoid the problem altogether by using a struct as opposed to a dictionary which I assume is preferred in Swift.

```
        let postscriptNames = fontFamilyMembers.map {
            (
                name: $0[0] as! String,
                weight: $0[2] as! Int,
                traits: $0[3] as! UInt
            )
        }

        lengths = postscriptNames.map { $0.name.count }
```

Comment: Using dicts like this requires all the members to be `Any`, or some other shared supertype. That becomes a mess of force unwrapping and casting. You should convert your data into stronger types as early as possible, like a struct or a class.

Comment: Yes. I came to realise that. I also decided to provide default values instead of just force unwrapping optionals. Eg: `name: $0[0] as? String ?? ""…`

Comment: I wouldn't advice that. `""` isn't a valid name. You've replaced one problem (crashing on `nil`) with another (polluting your data with junk on `nil`). I usually solve this problem by using a failable initializer that takes the raw dict (array in your case), and unwraps all the members, returns `nil` on encounting `nil` in any of them, otherwise forwarding all the non-nil properties as arguments to the default memberwise initializer.

Answer (score 2):

**Is that because postscriptNames is also type [Any]?**

Yes. And as `postscriptNames` is of type `[Any]`, you need to downcast `$0.name` to String

```
lengths = postscriptNames.compactMap { ($0.name as? String).count }
```

Downcast it to String to get the count.

Comment: `compactMap { $0.name as? String}` seems like a better approach than `map` with a default value.

Comment: @DávidPásztor true. updated the code. Thanks for the suggestion